# Code Access Security in .NET 4.0 when creating installer in Inno Setup

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, inno-setup

When I created installer with .NET2.0 application I always add that line:

```
Filename: {win}\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CasPol.exe; Parameters: "-q -machine -addgroup 1.2 -url ""file://{app}/*"" FullTrust -name ""MyApp"""; WorkingDir: {tmp}; Flags: skipifdoesntexist runhidden; StatusMsg: "Setting Program Access Permissions..."
```

Now, I want to create installer with .NET4.0 and I'm confused a little bit.

I don't know whether that is very important, but how can I replace it? So that it will work with .NET4.0?

Maybe I don't have to do anything in Inno setup script, and only in my app.config this?:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I don't know if that is important, but my app (windows service) will host WCF functions.

Comment: .NET 4.0 has mostly done away with machine-level code-access-security permissions, so you may be able to remove this step from your installer and be fine. I don't know enough of the details to know for sure if that's the case, though.

Comment: According to [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz(v=VS.100).aspx), your solution of adding the `<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>` to your app.config should get you the results you want.